# Can H4 visa holder travel with new name over passport

Tags: names, h4-visa

My wife is currently in India and her name is wrongly printed on her passport.

Passport:
Firstname = ABC DEF
Surname = Blank

H4 visa:
Firstname = FNU
Surname = ABC DEF

Now, since she is in India, so I am thinking of getting her passport corrected, i.e. splitting name in her passport. But the concern is, can she travel to USA with visa in old passport and updated name in new passport?